# Why can't I review a suggested edit to my answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, review

I received a "please review" notification of an edit suggested for [an answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/162988#162988) (It's also my question, but I think that's irrelevant). The edit seems good, and I wanted to approve it. But I couldn't see how to do this - I couldn't see a button or link or something to do it. I noticed the following two things:

1. It says that someone reviewed the edit.
2. Next to the user who suggested the edit, it says that 0 of his edits have been rejected, and 0 approved.

I take this to mean that the reviewer who looked at it didn't have a conclusive opinion and left it for the "next" reviewer to decide. But if that's true why can't I approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [post was merged](https://askubuntu.com/posts/161273/revisions), which I think is the cause of the confusion.

[image: Edit history w/merge]

Regardless, you wouldn't be asked to approve edits to your questions or answers. That isn't how the site works. Others [can make edits any time](https://askubuntu.com/faq#editing) and (with sufficient reputation) they are automatically approved.

If users make an edit to someone else's post, and have [less than 2000 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit), your edits are peer-reviewed by someone who does.

Comment: Still, that leaves us in the same situation- his edit hasn't been approved, and it doesn't seem like anyone is going to. I think in this case maybe I'll just take what he's suggested and integrate it into the post myself - but in that case he will lose the "credit" for a perfectly good suggestion.

Comment: In that case maybe this this should be flagged for a moderator to look at. I've never heard of users being asked to review edits to their own posts, so this may be a bug? Try flagging the post and leave a short message for a moderator asking for help. Also, you don't have to accept my answer above, it didn't really explain what happened. Here in Meta there is no reputation gain/loss so no pressure to accept anything. Good luck figuring it out though.

Comment: Ok, I flagged it. We'll see if it works out. BTW- I accepted your answer because I assumed that the merging WAS the reason why- I bet I'm not listed as the OP and the other question's OP is (I think his user has been deleted)